# How To Add Arabic to android application in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator

I am creating an android application
and want to use arabic font in the application
so when i use text view i copy and paste something in arabic
it shows up in weird numbers and letters
can you please help!
Thanks
Please Dont make it to complicated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first copy an Arabic font to your asset folder then create typeface from it; at the end you should convert utf-8 Arabic to Unicode Arabic[here i put the code for converting Persian to Unicode but it also should work for Arabic with minor modification]

[PersianReshape](http://codepad.org/hno0IxjN)

Comment: Can someone make it step by step? Thanks